# Better way to transform .doc into .pdf in a Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, shell, converters

I have a project in Laravel, that gets a few of doc files(like a 500 files) via API, and put it in a folder inside a storage folder, ok?

I did like to know the better way to transform all .doc inside that folder to .pdf

I can do it easily using shell scripts, there's a way to when I click in one button on a web page, "execute" this shell script?

Or what is the better way to do this?
PS: using a shell into terminal, I can convert 500 files using like 20 seconds.
If I try to convert one a one, i will expend so much time, is not a good idea I think;

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can run a command from your laravel application with this package
https://github.com/TitasGailius/terminal

example: `$response = Terminal::run('your_command');`

so you can combinate this with laravel queue https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues creating a queue that reads each file and then using the command above converter in pdf